JFrog Remote Repository
I recently started using Remote Repositories in JFrog. I understand that remote repositories act like proxies, connecting Artifactory to external repositories such as Maven Central. When an artifact is retrieved, Artifactory stores it in the local cache for future use
After that, Xray is only available in the cache repository. Is this because the artifacts are stored locally in the cache repository?
